# How can I format a column from a tab separated file?

Tags: c#, linq, file, csv

New to C# and Linq. I've tried searching, and I cant seem to get anywhere.

I'm trying to format the last column in the file. It's a monetary value and I want to format it to display 2 decimal places.

This function is splitting the data and sorting the files. I think the formatting should happen when putting the file back together but I'm not sure how to implement this.

```cs
static void SortData(string directory, string outputDirectory)
{
    var d = new DirectoryInfo(directory);
    Console.WriteLine("Sorting Files...");

    foreach (FileInfo fi in d.GetFiles())
    {
        // Read file
        var fileContents = File.ReadAllText(directory+ fi.Name);

        //split on carriage returns and line feeds, remove empty entries.
        var lines = fileContents.Split(new[] { '\r', '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        //Split each line on Tab
        var splitLines = lines.Select(l => l.Split(new[] { '\t' }));

        //splitLines is now an array of arrays.  Each splitLine entry is a line, and each entry of each splitline element is
        //a single field... so we should be able to sort how we want, e.g. by first field then by second field:
        var sortedLines = splitLines.OrderBy(sl => sl[0]).ThenBy(sl => sl[1]).ThenBy(sl => sl[2]).ThenBy(sl => sl[3]).ThenBy(sl => sl[4]).ThenBy(sl => sl[5]).ThenBy(sl => sl[6]);

        //put back together as TSV - put tabs back.
        var linesWithTabsAgain = sortedLines.Select(sl => string.Join("\t", sl));

        //put carriage returns/linefeeds back
        var linesWithCRLF = string.Join("\r\n", linesWithTabsAgain);

        File.WriteAllText(outputDirectory + fi.Name, linesWithCRLF);
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Sorting Complete");
}
```

Comment: If you want to format all numbers to "2 decimal places", it might be better to `decimal.Parse(value)` and get a decimal[][] before sorting, and then use `.ToString("F2")` to format it before file write.

Answer (score 0):

So what you need to do is that after you split your data, for each or the lines, parse the string value into the number and then format it back into string but with 2 digits.
Put the following line after `var sortedLines = splitLines.....`:

```
foreach(var sl in sortedLines)
{
    sl[6]=decimal.Parse(sl[6]).ToString("F2");
}
```